# Manage multiple addresses for the same contact in a Gmail contacts group

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I use a group in Gmail to spam my friends with an occasional email when I travel on business.

Some of my contacts have multiple live email addresses, which I would like in the list.

The latest version of Gmail doesn't allow you to edit these anymore. So I can't remove one address for a contact without removing the contact completely and re-adding the ones that I actually want.

Am I missing something? The older API (luckily still available) allows this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From contacts list, click on the contact you want to manage.
2. At the top are tabs with the groups the contact is associated with.
3. If this contact has multiple addresses, there will be a menu
   associated with the group.
4. Pull down the menu (little arrow) and choose which addresses should
   be used for the group.

It seems that this method is working with the old version of the contacts list. If you don't see the set of group tabs at the top of the contact page, go to the menu on the left side and look for the option that says Leave the contacts preview. Clicking that should take you to a version of the list that allows you to edit the group contact addresses as I explained.

Answer (score 1):

- The latest version of Gmail certainly allows you to remove contact's email address. Just click edit on the contact, and click `remove` to the right of the email address.
- All messages bound for groups hit the primary-email of each recipient, (the first in the contact listing). There is no way that I know of to change this without clearing all the email addresses of the contact.

Unfortunately Gmail has always had pretty poor contact functionality. The system is great, the rolodex is great, but the integration with the system has always been lagging demand. We just got the ability to map dates onto a Google Calendar. Give them another 4-5 years.

Comment: I just double checked in gmail. In the current version, I see each person once & can't tell what email address.
Switch to "older version" (bottom of page) and the same group has 1 person twice (two addresses) and some of the addresses are not the primary contact.
So gmail seems to keeps addresses, not people.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for me was to edit the contact, deleting the address you don't want on this  list. Then save the contact, reopen and add the previously deleted  email address. The formerly second-listed address will now be the first listed address and hence the default email address for any labels/groups the person is part of. But that will be for **all** groups they're part of.