# How do you setup a contact in Gmail to send to two email addresses?

Tags: gmail, gmail-contacts

I have some contacts that have two email addresses and want group emails to go to both of them.  Is there a way to setup one contact so that group emails will go to two different email addresses, or will I just have to create another contact for them?

[Related Question.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/how-to-manage-multiple-addresses-for-the-same-contact-in-a-gmail-contacts-group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the main email address of a contact to contain multiple addresses.

Example: `person1@domain.com>, <person2@domain.com`

Via: http://instanticity.com/blog/gmail-multiple-contact-addresses-groups/

Comment: You're the man!

Comment: See new solution: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20301/sending-an-e-mail-to-all-addresses-of-all-contacts-in-a-contact-group-in-gmail/20468#20468?newreg=439f1c8512694db5b681bfcacaf47594

Answer (score 2):

Create a Group (look under Contacts). Create 2 contacts for the 2 addresses, and add them both to the group. When emailing, rather than emailing the contact, email to the group.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid, but I guess I probably have to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to set up another contact with the second mail address. By default the email will only be sent to one of the contact mail addresses.