# Sending an E-mail to all addresses of all contacts in a contact group in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I'm trying to send an E-mail message using Gmail to a contact group where some of the contacts have more than one E-mail address and I want to send the mail to all of them.

Is there a way for me to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're talking about a single contact having more than one email address and you want to send to those email address if that contact is in a particular group.

To do this you must first *manually* add that contact's second/third/etc email address to the contact group. You can do this two ways:

**If contact is already in the group**

1. Select **Contacts**
2. Click the person
3. Directly under the person's name you should see the group
4. Click on the **group label** and add the additional address you want

**If contact isn't in the group**

1. Click **Contacts**
2. Click **group name**
3. Click Add to **group name**
4. Add the email addresses (you will do this twice for one contact if they have two addresses)

**Now here's the trick**:
After manually adding multiple email addresses of the same contact to the group, instead of emailing through the groups pane, click **Compose** from the left hand navigation. In the **To** field, type your **group name** and hit **enter**. You should see all email addresses including multiple ones from a single contact.

Comment: Thanks. One clarification - I'm talking about a group which already has several such contacts (each having multiple E-mail addresses), and I want to compose the mail to all the addresses of all the contacts in the group.

Comment: Right, but I think there's a bug in Gmail Contacts. If you're in the Contacts page and select everyone in that group to email, it will only select the first email of the multiple listed for that contact. But, if you press the Compose button instead in the far top left, then within the 'To' field, type out the group name and hit enter, you should see all the email addresses. When the group is placed in the 'To' field, it should show every email address from each individual contact in that group.

Answer (score 5):

I think that this is the way to do it :

When composing an email, instead of typing in the group name into the address box, click the "To:", "Cc:" or "Bcc:" labels in front of that box.  This will open a pop-up which allows you to select addresses from your contacts.  At the top of the pop-up, you can select the group you want, then click on Select: All (all addresses should show up in the list below - including multiple addresses per contact), and Done.  You should now see all of the desired email addresses in the composition window.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=6c9284873181057c&hl=en

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail will do this as described above by using the selective Fields TO: or CC: or BCC: and then select your group and check mark select All. however this is hardly an elegant solution to a basic simple task since then All email addresses from All Contacts in your group will be used, when that may not be desirable for All Contacts.

Surprising for Google when simple check boxes would suffice to determine the action for any Contact within a Group... after all, this was the purpose of Groups, to simplify the process rather than encumber it with unneeded or unwanted complexity.

Answer (score 0):

In your contacts, select the mail list/group. You should see each "contact".  Then select the contact with multiple emails.  This will take you to the details for that individual contact.  Near the top, under the area where it says "job description, Company" you should see a little drop down with the name of the list/group in it.  Click the down arrow, which will expose the multiple addresses.  Next to each email, there is a check box.  The ones checked will get mail when sent to the list, so put a check in the additional email address checkboxes.  Once you do this, moving forward, all mails to the group will get the email, including the multiple addresses you checked.